# list Values to dataTable

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I created a list from an excel document that has partnumbers on the every other starting with the first, and prices on every other row, starting with the second.

Lets say I initialize a datatable like so..

```
         DataTable priceListTable = new DataTable();
         priceListTable.Columns.Add("ItemNumber", typeof(string));
         priceListTable.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(Float));
```

And my list (called recordList) looks this;

```
001-001
1.45 
001-002
3.49
```

How do I get the first two rows of the  list to fill the columns of the dataTable?

Comment: Do you have any attempts at implementing this that you could show?

Comment: I don't even know where to begin.

I was thinking a foreach loop, but needing two values (two rows of the list) makes that impossible right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution.

Loop over the list 2 items at a time starting from the 2nd item. This makes sure you always have a pair of items to use.

```
for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; i += 2)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();
    row["ItemNumber"] = list[i-1];
    row["Price"] = list[i];

    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string ItemNumber = "ItemNumber";
         string Price = "Price";
         DataTable priceListTable = new DataTable();
         DataRow row;
         priceListTable.Columns.Add(ItemNumber);
         priceListTable.Columns.Add(Price);
         int counter = 0;


        foreach(string s in recordList)
        {
            myTableSize++;
        }



       foreach(string s in recordList)
       {
           if (counter < myTableSize)
           {
               row = priceListTable.NewRow();
               row[ItemNumber] = recordList[counter];
               row[Price] = recordList[counter + 1];
               priceListTable.Rows.Add(row);
               counter++;
               counter++;
           }
```